# Check if two Strings contain the same pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching

my application is going to need a string matching function between an inputed string and a string stored in my DB. Those strings concerns product dimensions (like length, heigh etc.) My goal is to check if the string inputed already exists in my database but maybe with another pattern , for example :

input : "vis 4*40" should return true if I have something like "vis 4X40" or "vis 4 x 40" or "vis 4* 40" in my database.

The only way i've found yet is to normalize my databse using a regexp to replace pattern like :

```
 \d+ *[xX*] *\d+
```

with a normalized one (for example NumberXNumber), do the same with the string in input then try to find it. However I was wondering if any tool already existed and would allow me to do that. (I'm working in C# .NET V4)

Comment: if I get ur question right..u can can test the **input** string and **stored** string with the above `regex`..if both of them match then it already exist

Comment: I should have detailled more but in this case this should not match "vis 4x40" and "vis 4x60" event if the two match the regexp

Comment: check out my ans for what i actually meant

Comment: Is "fixing" your database possible? separate this data in to different columns?

Comment: @hometoast technically its possible, why ?

Comment: @WizardLizard, any time you're trying to parse a column in to different parts as part of your 'normal' business logic, that's a *very good* indicator that the you should separate the data in to distinct columns/fields.

Comment: @hometoast I thought of that in the beginning, the main issue is that the DB is fed by users from CSV files and its hard to teach to every of them to separate the fields. Of course if i can't fin any reliable solution i'll head in this direction.

Comment: There's the problem: you're letting end users feed the DB seemingly without much checks in between.   Parse and Validate user input before storing, and then you can read the data you need, and simply *format* it for the user later.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to concatenate both the data and then match them

```
string target=inputString+"#"+storedString;

if(Regex.IsMatch(target,"(\d+) *[xX*] *(\d+)#\1 *([xX*]) *\2"))
        //the string is in the database
else
       //it is not
```

Comment: I don't agree that this is better. What if any of the strings contains the separator character `-`? Or what if they will, sometimes in the future? That could be a nasty bug to find.

Comment: @DavidPärsson sure..but this is not the case with regex only..even if you do this in another way there would be changes even in that

Comment: David raise a good point, I know regexp are a tricky tool to use, I'm going to try your solution which should temporarily replace my method, if any big issues is reported i'll let you know and go back to my 1st idea. Thanks for the answer anyway :D

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: The separator character is only an issue if you concatenate the strings. You could create a similar matching feature based on the found groups, without concatenating the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the user-provided wildcard, replace the `*` with `%` and query your table: `SELECT col FROM table WHERE col LIKE 'vis 4%40'`

*Please* make sure you execute your queries with parameters.

Comment: Wouldn't this match for example `vis 40*40` as well as `vis 4*40`?

Comment: You're correct. My _real_ answer would have been: fix the database.